# How to create a log of an rsync transfer on the remote server?

Tags: server, bash, ssh, backup, rsync

I have a lovely functional bash script, which uses rsync to create a backup on a remote server, utilising key-based authentication.

It uses a standalone rsync command, rather than having to set up an rsync server. It runs on a cron job, for a user specifically created to handle the sync process.

It writes logs to  a directory in `/var/log` on the local machine, and everything is great. I would like it to be possible to write logs to the remote server too, which is where I'm a bit stuck.

I'd like to avoid having to use another rsync command to transfer the local log file within the script if possible, but if that's the only sensible way, so be it.

Is there a simple mechanism to write a log on the remote end?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I doubt it would be possible. I'm pretty sure it won't be worth the effort though. Why don't you want to use a second `rsync` or even just an `scp` to copy the log over?

Comment: No real reason @terdon I was just wondering if I'd missed something from the rsync man page. I was thinking about only allowing rsync access to the directory that holds the data, and would like to keep the logging separate from the data, but a controlled `scp` might be sensible. I guess just using the correct permission on a directory within `/var/log` is the way to go.

Comment: You could also do a reverse copy: ssh to the target and rsync from the source. Something like `ssh user@remote rsync user@local:/path/to/local /path/to/remote/ 2> /path/to/remote.logfile`. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Would that require an open port on the router at the local end? Or would the `rsync` work through the already created ssh connection? @terdon

Comment: It would require the open port. You could probably set up a reverse ssh  but I don't know how off the top of my head. Try looking up reverse ssh tunnels.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @terdon a second `rsync` or `scp` definitely looks like the way to go.